# IntelliJ - is it possible to use loops in watches? or in custom class renderers?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

This is an odd problem:

I need to debug code which uses complex value objects and, often, collections of them. But I'm only interested in certain member of the objects at a time. Conceptually, let's say I need to watch every SmallToe on every Person on a Bus.

(Given a `Bus<Person>` which is an instance of `class Bus extends ArrayList`) I would like to write this in debug watches:

```
for(int i=0; i<bus.size(); i++) {
    bus.get(i).getLeg().getSmallToe().getDesc();
}
```

But this, of course, doesn't parse ('Unexpected tokens'). Are loops in watches even legal (or in Intellij custom java class renderers) and can this be done somehow? Is there any other way you'd go about this?

Alternatives, such as a) writing `get(x).getLeg().getSmallToe().getDesc();` many times (separate watches) and b) having to expand a tree full of members and sub-members, which is 10-screens-long, are not very exciting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code fragments are not yet possible in watches, however there's no problems with implementing them one day. I've filed [IDEA-178815](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178815), please vote.

In your case you can try using streams to fit it into a watch expression, something like:

```
bus.stream().map(p -> p.getLeg().getSmallToe().getDesc()).toArray()
```

However this could be slow to evaluate on every step...

Code fragments are available in renderers expressions, but then you'll need to replace the whole class children with your new, something like this:
[image: renderers setup]

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful!

In Java Type Renderers should I be able to declare type rendered to be a `java.util.ArrayList<Person>`? I get parsing errors on List, but maybe I'm mistyping something. (I realise I wasn't clear about this: the Bus in my example is not a `class Bus extends ArrayList<Person>` but rather a non-generic ArrayList extension, which is parametrised with <Person> when declared.)

Comment: Ahh, this isn't going to work in IntelliJ 14.1.5, right? The code fragments in renderers are a newer feature than that? Sadly, we are limited to this version for in-house plugin reasons.